# mac os x terminal problem faced

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, terminal, osx-snow-leopard

oh my god...i faced a big problem...i was created a .bash_profile in ~ folder and then set paths there...bust the big problem is after restarting my bash i see that none of my commands work like LS and RM and etc...

now i dont know how to fix it...some one help me...i need my terminal as soon as possible...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are appending to the existing $PATH.

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/mthalman/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this happening in the future:

When I edit my environment files (including bashrc, profile, login, and others), I always try starting another  shell before quitting my editing environment. This protects me from the possibility of breaking my environment so that I can't log in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PATH includes the usual `bin` directories: `/bin` and `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

First I would rename `~/.bash_profile` to `~/old.bash_profile`.

Then open that up in TextEdit (as a plain text document) and verify how you have set your path.

If you would prefer to use vim/emacs/nano/whatever, the act of renaming the file will allow new terminal sessions to use default paths, so from the command line you should be mostly fine.

Then verify you haven't clobbered `$PATH` as suggested by @Mark Thalman, above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Terminal Window, simply add in the `/bin` and `/usr/bin` back in your PATH.

```
$ PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

That should allow all the basic Unix command to work once more. Or, you can use the full path name for commands:

```
$ PATH=""  #Can't find nothin'
$ ls
bash: ls: command not found.
$ /bin/ls -a  #This will work!
.   ..   .bash_profile   foo   bar
```

---

### Don't Reset PATH in your .profile!

As you discovered, you should **never** reset PATH in your `.bash_profile. Instead, you should always append and prepend to it:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

The first line will prepend `/usr/local/bin` to PATH which means if a command is in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin`, the `/usr/local/bin` version will be executed. Many system admins will put alternative base system commands in `/usr/local/bin`. For example, on Solaris, they might put VIM in `/usr/local/bin/vi`, so when you edit a file, you're using the improved VIM and not the base VI.

The second line appends your `$HOME/bin` to the end of `$PATH`. That means if there's a `/bin/ls` and you have `~/bin/ls`, the `/bin/ls` will be executed first.

Never set PATH from scratch because each Unix system might have commands that you to access elsewhere in the system. For example, your site might require you to use X11, so you want /usr/X11/bin in your PATH, or you have GIT installed under the `/opt/git` directory, and you'll need `/opt/git/bin` in your path.

Sometimes, base utilities like `ls` might be replaced with *upgraded* versions of these utilities. On Solaris, you have the base `vi` and `ls` command, Most users like the GNU `ls` command because it uses color and prefer VIM to plain VI. I would included these utilities in `/usr/local/bin` and prepend that to my PATH.

---

### And now a Word from a Sponsor

As you probably discovered, Finder doesn't list *hidden* files. That's why you can't see `.bash_profile` in Finder. You can use some hacks to change this, but it requires you to type them into the terminal window.

I use a Finder replacement called [Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/). It contains a lot of neat *Power User* things such as allowing you to see hidden files, treat *Packages* such as apps as directories, and be able to view protected directories if you have Administrator access. There's a built in terminal and GUI Subversion client.

It's not cheap ($40), but you can download for free and try it out for 30 days.

BTW, I have absolutely no relationship to Cocoatech except as a customer, and I make no money from people buying Path Finder. It's just a tool I use.