# Built Ruby from source on OS X, now I want to use it

Tags: ruby, build

Edit:  This question is not very particular to ruby, and more related to how linking binaries in UNIX works.  I'm pretty sure that's where my question lies.

I built Ruby 2.1.1 and it installed in /usr/local/bin/ruby

My version of OS X comes with Ruby 1.8.7 in /usr/bin/ruby

**What is the recommended way for making my operating system default to using the new version of ruby when I run it?**  In other words, if I just run `ruby`, or `gem`, it is finding the binaries in /usr/bin first.  I have to run the new ones by specifying the full paths.

To build, I ran `./configure`, `make`, then `sudo make install`.  Would it have made any difference to be super user at either of the first two steps?

Comment: The simplest way would be just to prepend `/usr/local/bin/ruby` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks.  That actually makes sense - I've only ever appended.  Is this the recommended, long-term solution?

Comment: I don't see why not. There might be a more OSX-specific way, but I can't see any negative affects from just adding it to the front of your `PATH`.

Comment: If you want to modify the “default” paths system-wide, edit `/etc/paths`.

Comment: It seems a little intense to modify default paths, system-wide, to solve this one issue with ruby.  Or am I just being a pansy?  That file looks very fundamental to how my operating system behaves.

Comment: Maybe check into [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I see is just to add the following line to `~/.profile`

```
export PATH='/usr/local/bin':$PATH
```

Which should make bash find your new Ruby binaries before the preinstalled ones.

Comment: Actually, there is no `.bashrc` on a basic OS X system.  This worked when I put it in `~/.profile`  Maybe you should append the answer.  I'll still accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, my PATH variable updated as expected, but `ruby -v` still says 1.8.7, dammit!

Comment: It's because the *binary* is *at* `/usr/local/bin/ruby`.  The directory is `/usr/local/bin`.  My bad - that may have been confusing from my original question.  It is probably a bad idea to prepend `/usr/bin/local` to my PATH...

Comment: Actually, I think you'd probably be fine to add /usr/local/bin to the front of your `PATH`. All that means is that any utility you install from source will override existing utilities. David W.'s answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248622/mac-os-x-terminal-problem-faced seems to suggest that it's common practice to keep /usr/local/bin at the front of your `PATH`.